# How can i get the the two nodes (coordinates) between a edge? In OSMNX if i had (u,v,x) by ox.distance.nearest_edges

Tags: python, python-3.x, graph, networkx, openstreetmap

I have the id's of an edge and I want to get the coordinates(x,y) of the nodes inside it, I try this way:

```
#this is my graph:
G = ox.graph_from_address('Arequipa, Arequipa', `network_type='drive',simplify=True,dist=7000)


#where nearestEdge[x][0] = u, nearesEdge[x][1] = v
coordinates_edges = G.edges[nearestEdge[0][0], nearestEdge[0][1],0]
print(coordinates_edges)
```

Output:

```
 {'osmid': 571036931, 'highway': 'residential', 'oneway': False, 'length': 55.707}
```

if I try:

```
coordinates_edges = G.edges[nearestEdge[0][0], nearestEdge[0][1],0]['geometry']
```

I get this error:

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-52-20f93c142504> in <module>()
      8 #coordinates_nodes = G.nodes[5517424179]['y']
      9 
---> 10 coordinates_edges = G.edges[nearestEdge[0][0], nearestEdge[0][1],0]['geometry']
     11 print(coordinates_edges)
     12 

KeyError: 'geometry'
```

Comment: Where is the `nearestEdge` variable defined?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not totally clear what you mean by:

> How can i get the the two nodes (coordinates) between a edge?

If you're asking how do you get the coordinates of the two nodes that an edge connects, you can do something like:

```py
import osmnx as ox
G = ox.graph_from_address('Arequipa, Arequipa', network_type='drive',  simplify=True,dist=7000)
edge = list(G.edges)[0]

node1 = edge[0]
node1_x = G.nodes[node1]['x']
node1_y = G.nodes[node1]['y']

node2 = edge[1]
node2_x = G.nodes[node2]['x']
node2_y = G.nodes[node2]['y']
print(node1_x, node1_y, node2_x, node2_y)
```

Read through the OSMnx [documentation](https://osmnx.readthedocs.io/) and the NetworkX [documentation](https://networkx.org/) to familiarize yourself with basic functionality like this.